# Distribution of code of a system that uses open source tool with GPL license

Tags: gpl, source-code, gnu, license

I'm sorry if my question is repeated, but I have searched and read allot about this topic and kind of confused and want to make sure at this point. I'm planning to use an open source tool that will be installed on my server, it will be online and users can have access to it. Does that implicate that I have to distribute the source code in this case?

Noting that the license is GPL 3 
If so, how people are using Drupal for example? as I understand this situation, they must distribute their modifications?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifications of server software under GPL, with web/CLI interface](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5047/modifications-of-server-software-under-gpl-with-web-cli-interface)

Answer (score 1):

No, as long as you do not release the source code or the binary to them, you are not required to release any source code. However there is another license - https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affero_General_Public_License which **DOES** require you to do that and was written explicitly with that in mind.

In short:
GPL 3 **does** NOT require you to give source code for programs which run only on your server and you are not distributing them
AGPL 3 **does** require you to give source code for programs which run only on your server and you are not distributing them